# Problem writing UTF-8 encoded file in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a large file that contains world countries/regions that I'm seperating into smaller files based on individual countries/regions. The original file contains entries like:

```
  EE.04 Järvamaa
  EE.05 Jõgevamaa
  EE.07 Läänemaa
```

However when I extract that and write it to a new file, the text becomes:

```
  EE.04  JÃ¤rvamaa
  EE.05  JÃµgevamaa
  EE.07  LÃ¤Ã¤nemaa
```

To save my files I'm using the following code:

```
mb_detect_encoding($text, "UTF-8") == "UTF-8" ? : $text = utf8_encode($text);
$fp = fopen(MY_LOCATION,'wb');
fwrite($fp,$text);
fclose($fp);
```

I tried saving the files with and without utf8_encode() and neither seems to work. How would I go about saving the original encoding (which is UTF8)?

Thank you!

Comment: is the editor with which you're viewing the generated file interpreting it as UTF8? :)

Comment: Do you do any processing to your file after reading it? Is your PHP source file in UTF-8?

Comment: Btw. I wouldn't rely on mb_detect_encoding. If you know that the $text is already in utf8 just remove that as well as the call to utf8_encode.

Comment: @Raoul, yeah I'm using the same editor to view both files (the original and the new file).
@dionyziz, yeah it is. Would it make a difference it if wasn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't depend on `mb_detect_encoding`.  It's not great at figuring out what the encoding is unless there's a bunch of encoding specific entities (meaning entities that are invalid in other encodings).

Try just getting rid of the `mb_detect_encoding` line all together.

Oh, and [`utf8_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) turns a `Latin-1` string into a `UTF-8` string (not from an arbitrary charset to `UTF-8`, which is what you really want)...  You want [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), but you need to know the source encoding (and since you can't really trust `mb_detect_encoding`, you'll need to figure it out some other way).

Or you can try using `iconv` with a empty input encoding `$str = iconv('', 'UTF-8', $str);` (which may or may not work)...

Comment: When I used iconv with an empty input encoding it gives me a notice that the function "Detected an illegal character in input string" and the output is still messed. How would I go about trying to figure out the source encoding?

Comment: You could try using [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php) and feeding the result into `iconv`.  But realize there are some limitations to the charsets that it can detect.  If it returns `false`, your other option is to bust out a hex editor and find the entities for a known multi-byte character and then try searching for that glyph on the internet to try to figure out what encoding it is.  Where did you get the files from (That may provide a hint)...

Comment: @ircmaxell, I got the file from geonames.org (http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt). According to the website the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Well, it's likely not valid `UTF-8` then.  Even if it had a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) it would be treated like a normal character...  So something else is going on.  The only thing I could say is to use [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as a reference with a hex editor and try to find out where the invalid character(s) is(are)...

Comment: The output I got was:
   ef 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Well, `ef` is the start of a three byte sequence.  `41` is a single byte encoded `A` character.  So that's the invalid encoding...  Are there really a bunch of `A` characters at the start of the file?  I'd suggest re-downloading the file and seeing if it's still corrupt.  If not, you COULD try running this: `$string = str_replace(chr(239).chr(65).chr(65), chr(239).chr(197).chr(191).chr(65).chr(65), $string)` which will try to manually expand out the `ef` to a full BOM marker (`ef bb bf` in hex, `239 187 191` in decimal)...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work like that. Even if you utf8_encode($theString) you will not CREATE a UTF8 file.

The correct answer has something to do with the **UTF-8 byte-order mark**.

This to understand the issue:
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
- http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

The solution is the following:
As the UTF-8 byte-order mark is '\xef\xbb\xbf' we should add it to the document's header.

```
<?php
function writeStringToFile($file, $string){
$f=fopen($file, "wb");
$file="\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string; // utf8 bom
fputs($f, $string);
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

The $file could be anything text or xml...
The $string is your UTF8 encoded string.

Try it now and it will write a UTF8 encoded file with your UTF8 content (string).

```
writeStringToFile('test.xml', 'éèàç');
```

Comment: UTF-8 related materials suggest to not create UTF-8 files with a BOM. Can you explain why you think you suggest to do otherwise? Also the code you've posted has errors and does not work as you describe it to work. Please review.

Comment: Sorry, hakra, I fixed it.
I am using BOM header as it doesn't work for me any other way.
For example the solution bellow produce the following result.
"This is a string Ã©Ã¨Ã Ã§ and it is in utf-8"
Creating a BOM header produce the expected result.
"This is a string éèàç and it is in utf-8"

Comment: I am not sure why you advise against this method as I don't think it will be possible doing otherwise. If you display the output on an HTML page and set the encoding to UTF8 it will display correctly, there is no need to change the BOM for an HTML file. But when it comes to text files, CSV and XML they are not UTF-8 encoded and simply declaring the document as UTF8 will not produce the expected result. Simply take out the sequence of bytes that signalize the UTF8 and try to write an xml file with the declaration of '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'. Add 'éèàç' as a node and check.

Comment: It's okay to use something if it works for you. I won't advice against a working solution, that was not my intend. More to make clear why you used it because - just an example - if I have a UTF-8 encoded file - be it CSV or HTML - I have not problem at all to deal with it even without BOM. So to make the context of the answer more clear for the reader. BOM in UTF-8 files can be problematic, e.g. when they aren't at the beginning or when they are placed multiple times within the file and such.

Comment: This is not a good answer, it's just a dirty fix. **Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8** http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to call `htmlentities($text)` before writing it into file and `html_entity_decode($fetchedData)` before output. It'll work with Scandinavian letters.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows:

```
<?php
$s = "This is a string éèàç and it is in utf-8";
$f = fopen('myFile',"w");
fwrite($f, utf8_encode($s));
fclose($f);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your source file is not, in fact, in UTF-8.  You might want to try using the same approach you've been using, but with a different encoding, such as UTF-16 perhaps.